# Magento CSS customization question by using gulp

Tags: theme, scss

I have issue getting gulp setup on my local DevOps
Can I just modify the scss file and modify the CSS manually?
Anything else I need to pay attention?

Comment: We need much more info than that, Gulp and Scss is not core Magento so can you at least explain how you have set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Magento 2 - Blank theme - SASS version](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass) it is a SCSS based version of Magento 2 Blank theme, which aims to be as close to the core code as possible.

You can compile SASS files using [Frontools](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools) or tools of choice. Frontools is a set of front-end tools for Magento 2, based on Gulp.js. It uses gulp, yarn, sass-lint, sass, csslint, browsersync, stylelint etc.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I knew I am asking a stupid question, for fast to get the work done, can I just manually modify the SCSS and CSS at the same time? Since I still have time to trouble shoot why I have problem by running the Gulp on the server

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that, but if it works for now..  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯